# functions to append and read from linked lists

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

I am working on a small test program which can perform 2 functions on a linked list:

1. append something to a linked list.
2. get the something that was appended.

So I wrote 2 functions which can perform exactly that. However it doesn't work. 
If I call the function `append_work()` it prints out that it appended the work and also the correct values I passed. However afterwards it doesn't seem to correctly set the pointer to the next struct. I don`t know why this is happening.

A similiar thing happens when I call `get_work()` it prints out the current work correctly but doesn't set it to the next one. The outptr is only there so that it returns the struct on the work to be done while stil settings the work_travel to the next one!

I am probably missing something really obvious with the pointers but I am not seeing it...

Here is the code. it compiles:

```
#define          _POSIX_C_SOURCE                             200809L  
#define          ERRNO_BUFSIZE                               256

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int strerror_r(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen);

typedef struct work work;

struct work {

    char                *str;
    int                 i;
    work                *next;

};

int append_work(work *ptr, char *work, int i) {
    char    strerror_buf[ERRNO_BUFSIZE];

    ptr->next = malloc(sizeof(work));
    if (ptr == NULL) {
        strerror_r(errno, strerror_buf, ERRNO_BUFSIZE);
        printf("malloc() err: %s\n",strerror_buf);
        return -1;
    }

    ptr = ptr->next;
    ptr->str=work;
    ptr->i=i;
    printf("appending work: %s\n",ptr->str);

    ptr->next = NULL;

    return 0;

}

int get_work(work *inptr, work *outptr) {

    if (inptr == NULL) {
        printf(" No work found...\n");
        return -1;
    } else {
        outptr = inptr;
        printf(" work found: str: %s|| int: %d\n",inptr->str, inptr->i);
        inptr = inptr->next;
        return 0;
    }
}



int main() {

    char                strerror_buf[ERRNO_BUFSIZE];

    work                *root;
    work                *work_travel;
    work                *add_work;
    work                *curr_work;

    root = malloc(sizeof(work));
    if (root == NULL) {
        strerror_r(errno, strerror_buf, ERRNO_BUFSIZE);
        printf("malloc() err: %s\n",strerror_buf);
        exit(1);
    }
    root->str="work 0";
    root->i=0;


    work_travel = root;
    add_work = root;

    append_work(add_work, "work 1", 1);
    append_work(add_work, "work 2", 2);
    append_work(add_work, "work 3", 3);
    append_work(add_work, "work 4", 4);
    append_work(add_work, "work 5", 5);
    append_work(add_work, "work 6", 6);
    append_work(add_work, "work 7", 7);
    append_work(add_work, "work 8", 8);
    append_work(add_work, "work 9", 9);

    get_work(work_travel, curr_work);
    get_work(work_travel, curr_work);
    get_work(work_travel, curr_work);

    exit(1);

}
```

Comment: something like double pointer might be of your help. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, having "struct work", a type named "work", and a variable named "work" is *really* bad programming style.

That said, the problem is that `inptr` is a local variable in `get_work`, changing it will not change `work_travel` when you call `get_work(work_travel, curr_work)`. You have to return the updated value somehow, either as a return value from get_work like (though with this solution you loose the success flag, not that you use it :-) ):

```
work *get_work (work *inptr, work *outptr) {
   ...
   return inptr;
}
```

and call it like:

```
work_travel = get_work(work_travel, curr_travel);
```

Or pass in a pointer to the to-be-updated object like:

```
int get_work (work **inptr_p, work *outptr) {
  work *inptr = *inptr_p;
  if (inptr == NULL) {
    printf(" No work found...\n");
    return -1;
  } else {
    outptr = inptr;
    printf(" work found: str: %s|| int: %d\n",inptr->str, inptr->i);
    inptr = inptr->next;
    *inptr_p = inptr;
    return 0;
  }
}
...
get_work (&work_travel, curr_travel);
```

Comment: I then will just have to check if get_work() returns a NUll then. And ofcourse I know using struct called work is bad practice but this is just a proof-of-concept

Answer (score 1):

You are never returning the new head for the list, you're changing `ptr` inside `append_work()` but the value of `add_work` in `main()` is not changing.

You should *return* the new list head, instead.

This is because C is strictly [call by value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_value); an argument is a copy of the same value in the caller's context, and changing the copy doesn't affect the caller's value. The type of the value doesn't matter, it's always a copy.

Comment: I thought if I change a pointer in a function that should persist within main? Why is this not the case

Comment: If it is strictly call by value. then why is my append work still appended if I traverse by hand in main?

Comment: If you change the content of the object the pointer points to that change would persist, however you are changing what you pass in. And, as the answer pointed out, that is just a copy of the original pointer.

Comment: @RG337 I'm sorry, I'm not sure what you mean. You should perhaps post a separate question with the exact code for that case, and people will have a look.

Comment: @LaszloLadanyi I see thank you. Basically what you are saying once I go beyond the pointer to the actual memory location it will persist. obvious actually...